# Wordpress User Registration with Aweber

Tags: wordpress, aweber

I'm looking into a membership website that will let customers signup as a free member. However, I also want the form to sign them up to aweber. Is there a way to do this?

Basically, the Wordpress registration form will let them signup as a subscriber and also opt them in to a newsletter feed on aweber. Is this possible? If so, any suggestions on how this can be achieved?